# Which Eclipse package should I download for PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, package, pydev

Which Eclipse package should I choose for Python development with [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/)?

Nothing on the Eclipse homepage tells me what to choose, and the PyDev documentation assumes I already have Eclipse installed. Does it matter which Eclipse package I choose?

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/eclipsepython.html

Comment: @Woeitg Unfortunately, the link is broken.

Comment: @LucM use this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170711191128/http://www.ics.uci.edu:80/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/eclipsepython.html

Comment: Should this question be changed to "*How do I setup Eclipse for Python development with PyDev?*" It could be viewed as a software recommendation in its current form.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you just plan on doing Python dev, I'd just go with [Platform Runtime Binary](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/).

After that, I'd follow the instructions http://pydev.org/download.html and http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html to install PyDev.

I use the same setup for Python development.  I also have the RadRails plugin for Ruby on Rails development.

Comment: Why not point to a more generic download page, instead of such a specific download?

Comment: Classic Eclipse bundles Java Development Toolkit (JDT), Eclipse Plugin Toolkit PDE and lots of other packages not needed for python dev, as pointed out in some answers below Platform runtime binaries are good point to start. for current version 4.2, Classic eclipse is 183 MB compared to Platform binaries which is just over 50 M

Comment: @mzzzzb the PyDev spell checker requires JDT it seems. [JDT Required](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2151588/1452227)

Answer (score 4):

PyDev was acquired by [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com), so you might want to check that one out as well.

Comment: Aptana has syntax highlighting for Django templates, Pydev didn't the last time I used it.

Comment: **Aptana has not been updated [since July 2014](https://github.com/aptana/studio3/wiki/Release-Notes)**. It should not be used, as it runs on an outdated version of Eclipse and PyDev.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Python, and nothing else - I would just get the "Runtime Binary" edition of Eclipse, and add the [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) extension. That way Eclipse starts up lightning fast, consumes less memory and generally gets in your way less. On top of that, you can always add in whatever extensions/plugins you find you need. The runtime is generally around 50MB, instead of the usual 100+ for the SDK or other versions.

You can always find the latest version here:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

At the time of this posting, that would be 3.6.1:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.1-201009090800/index.php#PlatformRuntime

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting started, I would recommend you [python easyeclipse](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/python.html).

Pydev can give some incompatibilities when using it together with other extensions.

Comment: This is extremely out-of-date information - be warned that [EasyEclipse project is dead 2010/2011](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/news/index.html) and [will wrongly constrain you to Eclipse 3.3.x plugins, which can cause no end of grief](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7392510/202229). (I'm wondering whether your comment on PyDev compatibility is still valid? I've never had any issues.)

Comment: My comment was from 2008, obviosuly some thing have changed :) Nowadays I would recommend Aptana. Cheers!

Comment: No probs just updating the old recommendation.

Comment: **EasyEclipse should not be used, as the project was [officially abandoned in 2011](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/news/index.html)**. The included version of PyDev 1.3.3 is over 8 years out of date.

Answer (score 2):

A useful shortcut is to download [EasyEclipse for PyDev](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/plugins/pydev.html).  This is a version of Eclipse already pre-configured for pydev, and seems to be easier to install than gathering all of the Eclipse pieces yourself.  Unfortunately it uses a rather old version of PyDev, but this is easily remedied by going to `Help > Software Updates >` and letting Eclipse grab the latest version (you'll need to change the PyDev location to SourceForge before doing this).

Comment: **EasyEclipse should not be used, as the project was [officially abandoned in 2011](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/news/index.html)**. The included version of PyDev 1.3.3 is over 8 years out of date.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer that you should use **Luna** which is a tool for Java developers creating Java EE and Web applications, surely you can add PyDev to it.

As you are getting started with python, eclipse and pydev, you probably need step-by-step process.

Either follow these simple steps or Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAa80SpQJHo).

**Step 1:** Download and install Eclipse(Luna)

**Step 2:** Open Eclipse >> Help >> Install New Software...

**Step 3:** In the 'Work with' textfield type : http://pydev.org/updates

**Step 4:** select checkbox PyDev >> next >> next >> finish

**Step 5:** It Will install but later a new frame will open,make sure to check on "Brainwy Software,PyDev,Brainwy >> OK

Eclipse will restart after you click ok.

**Step 6:** Click on File >> New >> Project >> PyDev Project >>

Now you have to add Interpreter.

**Step 7:** Click on "Please configure an interpreter before proceeding"

**Step 8:** Click on "Manual Config"

**Step 9:** Click on "New" then give interpreter Name(python 2.x.x or python 3.x.x the version you are using) or any other name as you like.

**Step 10:** Click on "Browse" to give path.

If you are using Windows it probably would be in C: drive,

If you are using Ubuntu it would be in "/usr/bin/python2.x"
or use command "whereis python" in terminal.

**Step 11:** After this Select the interpreter >> Finish.

And you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend http://www.liclipse.com/ if you want a simple and straightforward setup (especially for web development, as it also has editors for web-related contents, such as html, css, javascript) or getting only the Platform Runtime Binary (which is the lightest released Eclipse with things needed for Pydev, around 47 MB -- it can be gotten at: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/, selecting the version you want and then looking for the Platform Runtime Binary).

The install instructions are at: http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html (and from there a getting started manual follows).

Answer (score 0):

pydev and Python2.6 doesnt work with eclipse for C++.
Download the classic version and you should be good.

Comment: **Eclipse Classic is no longer supported as of 2014**. The last release was [Eclipse Classic 4.2.2](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-422/junosr2).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Aptana distribution of Eclipse the the easiest way to get PyDev these days...especially since it's now free for the full version.  If you download the Studio from here:  http://www.aptana.org/  You can easily install PyDev from their plugin manager once it's up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Usually no-one mention but [Eclipse do have Python support](http://specialmeaning.blogspot.com/2016/04/setting-up-eclipse-native-python.html) in its DLTK (dynamic languages toolkit) plugin set.
You certainly may want to try it.

Anyway it is not as much functional as [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org) plugin thus you can have it securely. PyDev asks to accept its certificate that is vulnerability to MIM attacks.

You may want to consider [PyCharm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) as it has also PyDev work [included](http://www.pydev.org/history_pydev.html). PyCharm team has own PyDev branch and had some work on its debugger. Some [details on this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/05/debugger-interview-with-pydev-and-pycharm/) collaboration.

Answer (score -1):

I use J2EE Eclipse for Python and Java development. It works well.
But Classic Eclipse should be enought.

Comment: **Eclipse Classic is no longer supported as of 2014**. The last release was [Eclipse Classic 4.2.2](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-422/junosr2).

Answer (score -1):

I would just get [ JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3 ].
its FREE, fully featured and most of all, its dedicated for Python development.

there are 3 other IDE's that are great too, and they do over 30 languages each,
without needing plugins and additional 18 more by adding plugins.
check out --> Brackets, Atom and Visual Studio Code.
they are all free. I suggest checking out PyCharm first.

Answer (score -1):

Easy Eclipse for python is good and  light weight tool. But, then you dont get any of the extra features from it.

I tried to start with Django learning, but thn this version wasn't enough for it.
If you only opt fr simple python codes, its a very good tool.

Comment: **EasyEclipse should not be used, as the project was [officially abandoned in 2011](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/news/index.html)**. The included version of PyDev 1.3.3 is over 8 years out of date.