# Eclipse 'Add CVS Repository' hangs on known-good settings

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ssh, cvs

I have a CVS server which is known to be ok (works from other machines).
I am trying to set up Eclipse to connect from an Ubuntu box.

The following command-line command succeeds:

```
cvs  -d ':extssh:myuser@myhost/path/to/repository' checkout myrepository
```

Yet when I do Eclipse 'Add CVS Repository' it hangs on this, using both extssh and pserver protocols. extssh using port 22.

(There's no error message, it just hangs. Regardless whether 'Validate connection on finish' is on or off.)
I verified that all of the settings are ok. Port 22 is not blocked.
I double-checked Preferences under 'General>Network Connections' and 'Team>CVS'
I do not think it is an issue with keyless ssh either.

This is on an Ubuntu box, but these exact same Eclipse CVS client settings succeed from a Mac box.
(The Ubuntu box uses 9.10, and Eclipse is installed as EasyEclipse 1.3.1, installed as user, not root.
Plugin org.eclipse.team.* versions are:
`(Ubuntu)

 org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh,.ssh2 3.2.100

 org.eclipse.team.ui,.core,.cvs.core,.cvs.ui 3.3.r33x_2007...

 (Mac)

 org.eclipse.team.cvs.ssh2 3.2.300

 org.eclipse.team.ui,.cvs.core,.cvs.ui 3.5.100.l20100527-0800`

**(EasyEclipse prevents me from upgrading the Ubuntu plugins, it insists these 4-year-old ones are the latest. Maybe an argument against using EasyEclipse.)**

How to troubleshoot? How to trace what is actually happening inside Eclipse?
(as 'cvs -t -t' would give)
(As a sidebar, Eclipse should actually be printing a proper error message.
I've checked every appnote and userguide I can find with Google.)

Comment: I'd say it might be the 4-year old plugins.  Your version numbers indicate it's 3.3.x based.  The latest release is 3.6.x, with 3.7.0 set to be released at the end of June.

Comment: Like I commented, EasyEclipse constrains users to the versions it blesses, and these are from the latest distro of EasyEclipse! My post is as much to alert and warn EasyEclipse users. The spirit of EasyEclipse is pretty good, since it's a pain updating Eclipse modules. But it's waaay out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consensus was that EasyEclipse prevents user from upgrading the (4-year-old) Ubuntu plugins,  insists that 3.3.x are the latest available, which cause this hang.

[As of 5/2011, EasyEclipse is retired unless a new maintainer steps up.](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/news/index.html)