# Eclipse version for python develpment

Tags: eclipse, pydev

What is the most clean Eclpse distro to use for python development?
All distro comes with Java plugin and other stuffs.

I just want a clean Eclipse distro + pydev.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Eclipse package to download for pydev?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243962/which-eclipse-package-to-download-for-pydev)

Answer (score 1):

For a pre-configured environment, see http://www.liclipse.com (note it's commercial -- and has other niceties).

Aside from it, the option is getting the [Platform Runtime Binary](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) and follow the instructions from http://pydev.org/download.html and http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html to install PyDev.